# Find uncommon lines in two files where order isn't important

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have two file like

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 6
```

and

```
3 1 
6 2
1 4
```

I would like to find the lines in `file2` not in `file1` where the order of fields is not important. The output should be:

```
1 2
2 3
```

I tried with `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file1 file2` but I think it doesn't work if the fields are reversed.

Comment: That's unfortunate... your last edit completely changes the problem scope and invalidates most (maybe all) of the answers.

Comment: I know, I am sorry... Should I make another question? Don t know what to do..

Comment: By reversing some of the lines in `file2` your expected output now makes no sense. Don't make a new question just edit this one.

Comment: @sudo_O why not? we can look for example if the same number are in the same line, e.g. in both files there are "1" and "3" on the same line, that means that they are both files. 1 2 qnd 2 3 aren't in both files

Comment: Your question does state that! `1 3` is different from `3 1` so as your question stands it should be output as not common. Does the solution need to support more than 2 fields per line? Are the fields always integer values? You need to specific to get a useful answer. Please try to describe the problem fully.

Comment: The file has only two fields per line, all the fields are integer.

Comment: See my edited answer, easily done with just a small edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small change to allow the order of the fields not to matter:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1" "$2];next}!($1" "$2 in a||$2" "$1 in a)' file2 file1
1 2
2 3
```

Note: You need to give `file2` first.

Answer (score 0):

```
sdiff -s file1 file2
```

and reformat output

Comment: Who ever upvoted this didn't understand the problem. `diff` doesn't help here.